# How to git merge again after incomplete "-s ours" merge?

Tags: git, version-control, git-merge

Let's say I have a repo with branch `main` containing files `a` and `b` containing "a" and "b", respectively. I add another branch `secondary` from this branch and modify the two files to now contain "a2" and "b2", respectively. I checkout back to main and

```
git merge secondary --no-ff -sours --no-commit
```

Then I manually move `a` from secondary to main and commit. Now it looks like I merged `secondary` into main, but this was only a partial merge since `b` is unchanged.

However, I cannot do a second merge like

```
git merge secondary
```

because git claims that `main` is

> Alredy up to date.

Which of course, judging by the file contents, is not the case.

How to I undo this and/or now perform a second merge based on the actual differences of the files in the two branches? How to proceed from here? In this simple example, its clear what to actually change. Additionally, a `git reset` to the state before the first merge combined with a new full merge resolves this. But what about more complicated cases where it's not immediately clear how each file changed?

Comment: did you commit avec the first merge ?

Answer (score 2):

`git merge -s ours` means *ignore their file tree entirely* and always succeeds.  Using the `--no-commit` option allows you to modify the resulting index (proposed next commit); the final `git commit` you run after this uses whatever is in Git's index as the merge tree.  The merge is now complete, and the file tree you supplied *is* the correct result, by definition:

> ... I cannot do a second merge ...

That's correct, because there's nothing left to merge.  You did the merge; you supplied the correct tree; there's no work for *Git* to perform.

> How to I undo this and/or now perform a second merge based on the actual differences of the files in the two branches?

Reset the merge or move back to a commit from before the merge.  But note that merge in general is not based on the difference between two files, or even between two commits.  It's based on the differences between the files stored in *three* commits.  One of the three inputs is the *merge base* commit.  (The `-s ours` case is an exception here since we're not interested in their tree at all, only in ours; there need not even *be* a merge base.)

In the general merge case, the *work* that is to be merged is a result of diffing the merge base against each tip commit, with two separate `git diff` invocations.  These changes must then be *combined*, and the *combined* changes must be applied to the snapshot from the merge base.  So if you have one file that's been mis-merged, you can find the merge base yourself:

```
git merge-base --all <hash1> <hash2>
```

then extract the three copies of the file:<sup>1</sup>

```
git show <base>:path/to/file > file.base
git show <hash1>:path/to/file > file.a
git show <hash2>:path/to/file > file.b
```

and use `git merge-file` to do a single file merge:

```
git merge-file file.a file.base file.b
```

for instance.  Inspect the resulting `file.a` merged file, resolve any conflicts correctly this time, and install into place and `git add` and `git commit`.  (For an `-s ours` style merge, you'd just extract the one desired copy of the file and put that into the index and working tree and commit, which you can do with either `git checkout <hash> -- <path>` or the new, generally-better but longer-winded-in-this-case `git restore`.)

> Additionally, a `git reset` to the state before the first merge combined with a new full merge resolves this.

Right.

> But what about more complicated cases where it's not immediately clear how each file changed?

If you do expect to need an occasional re-merge, it may be wise to let Git make the initial merge commit, and then do any subsequent patching manually.  That way, any future need to re-merge will just re-use Git's own merge.  It will be obvious what got manually patched afterward, as that's in a separate commit.  You'll need to define your own workflow here, though.

---

<sup>1</sup>If `git merge-base --all` produces two or more merge base commit hash IDs, there is no single correct merge base.  What to do in *that* case depends on what result you want.  You can do what Git does by default—do a recursive merge of the merge bases and use that as the new merge base—or just pick one of the two commits at random, or inspect the file in each commit, or anything else you can come up with.  The `git merge-file` command just needs one base input file though, so that it can do the combine-two-diffs thing.